# Bluetooth discovering the same device 10 times

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a Bluetooth App with Android studio. Today, I get a weird issue.
I got 3 Bluetooth devices, a smartphone, a tablet, and another device but we don't really care about it.

I'm executing the same App on both devices but the smartphone is on Android 8.1 (API 27) and the tablet is on Android 4.0.4 (API 15).
On the smartphone, the app work well. When I scan for nearby devices, I get 4 different devices.

But there is the problem. On the tablet, when I scan for nearby devices, I got almost 10 times each devices detected by my smartphone. I don't really know why both devices are not discovering like each other. Maybe the Android version is the reason of that error.

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) { // discover devices
            Scanned_devices = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            scanned_deviceName = Scanned_devices.getName();
            scanned_macAddress = Scanned_devices.getAddress();


            mDeviceList.add(scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
            Log.i("BT", scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);


            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices  = blueAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    try {
                        if (scanned_deviceName.equals(device.getName()) || scanned_macAddress.equals(device.getAddress())) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mDeviceList.remove(scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
                        } //else {
                            //mDeviceList.add(scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
                            //Log.i("BT", scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
                        //}
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("tag", "not working");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not working..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            Scanned_devices_ListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: try to set the adapter outside of the onReceive method and test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of thing to detect if the device already exist in my ArrayList, I tried this code :

```
if (!mDeviceList.contains(scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress))
            {
                mDeviceList.add(scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
                Log.i("BT", scanned_deviceName + "\n" + scanned_macAddress);
            }
```

This will check if an Array contain this String : 

`DeviceName
DeviceMac@`

If the condition is true, the String is added to the ArrayList.

If it's false (there is another String with the same contents in the ArrayList), the String isn't added to the ArrayList.